# Change View Cart button to add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When people click add to cart the cart gets changed to a "see your cart" in WooCommerce. This way people cannot add more of the same product later should they have changed their mind about the quantity etc. Is there a way to keep the add to cart button?

Comment: I just tested up the code on last WC and WP versions, it works perfectly and allow adding again any added item. if you want to remove the quantity reset on add to cart remove the `setTimeout()` function (3 lines in the jQuery code). If it doesn't work for you it's because you have some more customizations that are making trouble (that customizations can be due to your theme, a plugin or something changed or added by you). See it working [on this test server](https://www.cbleu.net/sites/woolast/shop/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Sorry I am a bit confused. When I add the code above it makes my add to cart into the view cart button. How do I ensure it doesn't disappear?

Comment: In WooCommerce by default, only simple products can be Ajax added to cart… So may be you are using a special theme that enable some other behaviors than WooCommerce default ones (or some other plugin or some other related custom code or you have made some changes in the related involved templates files)…

Comment: Okay thanks. Strange. I am using Flatsome. But the products are simple products (not variables), so it should work, but I guess the theme must overwrite it. Is there an easy solution to force the add to cart button back?

Comment: Never used FlatSome theme… As it's a closed Premium commercial theme, you will need to ask author support threads. Also maybe it's a plugin that is making trouble or some other code you added.